# Column value based on previous column value

Tags: oracle, function, oracle11g, window

I had a result set on Oracle like this table:

[image]

Is there a way to add a new column with the values based on the previous TEMREGIONAL column to be like that:

```
311,1,1,0
430,2,0,1
329,3,0,1
```

What I want is based on the TEMREGIONAL value, if it is 1, so all rows after that will be 1 to.

So if I have something like that:

```
311,1,0
430,2,0
329,3,1
334,4,0
323,5,0
324,6,0
326,7,0
```

The result should be:

```
311,1,0,0
430,2,0,0
329,3,1,0
334,4,0,1
323,5,0,1
324,6,0,1
326,7,0,1
```

What I want is to add a new column and after the row with the value 1 at the third column, all rows should have the value 1 in this new column.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `ignore nulls` addition of `lag` to find previous `1`, turning zeroes to `null`. This can be done in one pass.

> ```
> with a(
>   ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
>   , ORD
>   , TEMREGIONAL
> ) as (
> select 311,1,0 from dual union all
> select 430,2,0 from dual union all
> select 329,3,1 from dual union all
> select 334,4,0 from dual union all
> select 323,5,0 from dual union all
> select 324,6,0 from dual union all
> select 326,7,0 from dual
> )
> select
>   a.*
>   , coalesce(
>       lag(nullif(TEMREGIONAL, 0))
>       ignore nulls
>       over(order by ord asc)
>     , 0) as prev
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA | ORD | TEMREGIONAL | PREV
> --------------------: | --: | ----------: | ---:
>                   311 |   1 |           0 |    0
>                   430 |   2 |           0 |    0
>                   329 |   3 |           1 |    0
>                   334 |   4 |           0 |    1
>                   323 |   5 |           0 |    1
>                   324 |   6 |           0 |    1
>                   326 |   7 |           0 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=93ef9d2b448c97bc9515113c23154090)*

Answer (score 1):

For sample data

```
SQL> select * from test order by ord;

ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA        ORD TERMREGIONAL
--------------------- ---------- ------------
                  311          1            0
                  430          2            0
                  329          3            1
                  334          4            0
                  323          5            0
                  324          6            0
                  326          7            0

7 rows selected.
```

this might be one option:

```
SQL> with
  2  temp as
  3    -- find minimal ORD for which TERMREGIONAL = 1
  4    (select min(a.ord) min_ord
  5     from test a
  6     where a.termregional = 1
  7    )
  8  select t.id_orgao_inteligencia,
  9         t.ord,
 10         t.termregional,
 11         case when t.ord > m.min_ord then 1 else 0 end new_column
 12  from temp m cross join test t
 13  order by t.ord;

ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA        ORD TERMREGIONAL NEW_COLUMN
--------------------- ---------- ------------ ----------
                  311          1            0          0
                  430          2            0          0
                  329          3            1          0
                  334          4            0          1
                  323          5            0          1
                  324          6            0          1
                  326          7            0          1

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```